# Jquery click event no longer bound for newly created tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the following

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAkCM/1/)

I am using .on but it seems that the click event doesn't apply for newly created items.
How can the new items also listen to the on click event?

```
 $("#addNewAddresses").on("click", function () {
        console.log("adding an address");
        var $table = $(this).parent().find("table");
        var html = "<tr  class='item'>";
        html += "<td class='city'>";
        html += "<input id='City' class='inputStylized' type='text' placeholder='City'>";
        html += "</td>";

        html += "  </tr>"
        $(html).appendTo($table);
    });

    $(".city").on("click", function () {
        console.log("city was clicked");
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to delegate the event to the static closest parent or to the `document` itself like below:

```
$("#address-table").on("click", ".city", function () {
    console.log("city was clicked");
});
```

You can delegate to `document` this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".city", function () {
    console.log("city was clicked");
});
```

[**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kAkCM/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just put this :

```
$(".city").on("click", function () {
    console.log("city was clicked");
});
```

after `.appendTo` so the event will be set for the new appended input :)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4HZD/)